# Appending to StringBuffer (Java Servlets) Not Picking up as Attributes In Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

For some reason my code HTML that I am appending to a StringBuffer (sb) in the doGet method are not being picked up in the other servlet.

This is the HTML code I am appending to the StringBuffer sb:

```
/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    List<Course> courses = (List<Course>) context.getAttribute("COURSES");

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(getHeader());
    sb.append("<form action=\"/Assignment_2/addCourse\">");
    sb.append("<table border=\"2\">");
    //sb.append("<tr><td>");

    //sb.append("</tr></td>");
    sb.append("<select>"
            + "<option value = book>Book</option>"
            + "<option value=tablet>Tablet</option>"
            /*+ "<option value=xxxxxx>XXXXXXX</option>"
            + "<option value=yyyyy>YYYYY</option>"*/
            + "/select>");
    sb.append("<tr><td>Type</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"type\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr><td>Name</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr><td>Additional Info</td><td><input type=\"text\" info=\"Additional Info\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>");
    sb.append("<tr><td># of Copies</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"# of Copies\" value=\"\" /></td></tr>");

    /*for (Course course : courses) {
        sb.append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prerequisite\" value=\"" + course.getCode() + "\">" + course.getCode() + "</input> <br />");
    }*/


    sb.append("</td></tr><tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add\" /></td></tr></table></form>");
    sb.append("</body></html>");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(sb.toString());
}

public String getHeader() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<html>");
    sb.append("<head><title>Department Library</title></head><body>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

So after the user clicks Submit, The code goes here:

```
    /**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletContext();
    List<Course> courses = (List<Course>) context.getAttribute("COURSES");
    for (Course course : courses) {
        System.out.println(course);
    }

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(getHeader());

    sb.append("<table border=\"2\"><tr>"
            + "<td>ID</td>"
            + "<td>Type</td>"
            + "<td>Name</td>"
            + "<td>Additional Info</td>"
            + "<td>Available</td>"
            + "<td>Operation</td></tr>");
    for (Course course : courses) {
        sb.append("<tr><td>");
        sb.append(course.getMyId() + "</td><td>" + course.getType() + "</td>");
        /*sb.append("<td>");
        for (String str : course.getPrerequisites()) {
            sb.append(str + "  ");
        }*/
        sb.append("</td><td>"
                + course.getName());

        sb.append("</td><td>"
                + course.getAdditionalInfo());
        sb.append("</td><td>"
                + course.getAvailable());

        sb.append("</td><td><a href=\"edit?code="+course.getCode() +"\">Edit</a></td>");//</tr>");



    }
    sb.append("</table><a href=\"add\">Add Items</a></body></html>");


    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println(sb.toString());
}

public String getHeader() {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append("<html>");
    sb.append("<head><title>Department Library</title></head><body>");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This line:

```
for (Course course : courses) {
        System.out.println(course);
    }
```

Tells me that my data is fine...What is going on with the Servlets?

*************EDIT****************

When Adding the below (within the first method of my original post):

```
sb.append("<tr><td>Available</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"available\" value=\"\" /> </td></tr>");
```

to the doGet I receive that data in my table! But for some reason (in the same file):

```
sb.append("<tr><td>Additional Info</td><td><input type=\"text\" name=\"info\" value=\"\" /> </td></tr>");
```

isn't being read, e.g., it reads as 'null' in my table. I did not type 'null' for the input (just for clarification).

Also..My data/inputs are visible in the URL after clicking next/submit/add whatever to submit the form action inputs.

Comment: what are you getting after submit an empty table?

Comment: null is placed into the Additional Info (info) and Available (available) HTML thingy's...

Comment: Are you able to invoke your second servlet when you click on submit button?

Comment: Edited with something working..

Comment: SOLVED!!!!! WHUPS FORGOT TO ADDD IT TO CLASS!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
in  first method...

 /*for (Course course : courses) {
        sb.append("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prerequisite\" value=\"" + course.getCode() + "\">" + course.getCode() + "</input> <br />");
    }*/

in second method

String [] temp=request.getparameterbyValues("prerequisite");

 for (i=0;i<=temp.length;i++) {

        System.out.println(temp[i]);
    }
```

Comment: After uncommenting and running without errors; I still view 'null' where the data should sit.

Comment: Are you able to see multiple checkboxes on HTML after first method being loaded....

Comment: please Change your method from doGet to doPost that will solve your problem....because action default call do post

Answer (score 0):

you have not used values from request object in your second servlet. You are only reading values from context object.